# How to make pointers be four bytes instead of eight

Tags: apache-spark, jvm

I am reading in the spark documentation that I can set the pointers size.
I have to use the JVM flag:`-XX:+UseCompressedOops`, but it is not clear for me how I have to insert it in the `spark-env.sh` file. Can I set this flag by code?

Comment: There is probably set in something like this - https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/conf/spark-env.sh.template in one of the _JAVA_OPTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I set this flag by code?

#### NO. since jvm -xx options are pointers to jvm at startup. you cant set through code

This is example shell script you can refer to use.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
# Set Spark environment variables for your site in this file. Some useful
# variables to set are:
# - MESOS_HOME, to point to your Mesos installation
# - SCALA_HOME, to point to your Scala installation
# - SPARK_CLASSPATH, to add elements to Spark's classpath
# - SPARK_JAVA_OPTS, to add JVM options
# - SPARK_MEM, to change the amount of memory used per node (this should
# be in the same format as the JVM's -Xmx option, e.g. 300m or 1g).
# - SPARK_LIBRARY_PATH, to add extra search paths for native libraries.
export SPARK_MEM="5000m"
BASEDIR=/root
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
export SCALA_HOME=$BASEDIR/scala-2.8.1.final
export MESOS_HOME=$BASEDIR/mesos
JARS=
JARS+=$BASEDIR/spark/conf/
JARS+=:/nfs/spark/alignerscala_2.8.1-1.0.jar
JARS+=:$SCALA_HOME/lib/scala-library.jar:$SCALA_HOME/lib/scala-compiler.jar
export SPARK_CLASSPATH=$JARS
#export SPARK_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.default.parallelism=40 -Dspark.cache.class=spark.SerializingCache -Dspark.boundedMemoryCache.memoryFraction=0.50 -XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis -Dspark.task.cpus=1 -XX:NewRatio=7 -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
#export SPARK_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.default.parallelism=40 -Dspark.cache.class=spark.SerializingCache -Dspark.boundedMemoryCache.memoryFraction=0.50 -XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis -Dspark.task.cpus=1 -XX:+UseCompressedOops"
#export SPARK_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.default.parallelism=40 -XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis -Dspark.task.cpus=2 -XX:+UseCompressedOops"
#export SPARK_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.default.parallelism=40 -XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis -Dspark.task.cpus=1 -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Dspark.serialization=spark.KryoSerialization -Dspark.cache.class=spark.SerializingCache -Dspark.boundedMemoryCache.memoryFraction=0.8 -Dspark.locality.wait=10000 -Dspark.kryo.registrator=SparseVectorOriginalRegistrator"
export SPARK_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.default.parallelism=4 -XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis -Dspark.task.cpus=1 -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Dspark.boundedMemoryCache.memoryFraction=0.8 -Dspark.locality.wait=10000"
#export SPARK_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.default.parallelism=40 -XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis -Dspark.task.cpus=2 -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Dspark.serialization=spark.KryoSerialization -Dspark.locality.wait=10000"
```

Comment: Sorry but i am new with Spark. I forgot to specify that i am using Intellij and I am writing a self contained app. I found a spark-env.sh file. Is this the file that I have to modify writing SPARK_JAVA_OPTS?

Comment: Yes that's the file

Comment: XX:+UseCompressedOops is there in example script if you scroll to the right

Comment: also I dont understand why you quoted intellij... you are asking whether can apply vm options or not ? please see [vm options](http://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/setting-configuration-options.html)

Comment: Thanks, and how can I check if my UseCompressedOops option is applied to Spark?